# How to open a new JFrame through a JMenu Item?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenu

Right, so I already looked at multiple questions regarding something close to this but not what I need help with.

What my issue is, what would I call so that when "New" is clicked, a new Frame would open (the same but just opened again).
The system prints out the string, so I know it's working. I just need to figure out how to open a new window.

```
 mntmNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Opening a new window.");

            }
        });
```

Comment: How did you show the first window? You should be able to use the same code if you got it to display once.

Comment: It's exactly the same as how you'd open and create **any** JFrame. Surely you can extrapolate from this, no? And regarding, `"Right, so I already looked at multiple questions regarding something close to this but not what I need help with."` -- you will want to work on those search skills, and in fact please understand that you can search this site: [check this search result](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+open+new+jframe).

Comment: Also, please have a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

```
YourJFrameClass frame = new YourJFrameClass();
frame.<function to show it>();
```

then you will maybe make it modal or close the previous one.

Comment: How would you make a JFrame modal?? Surely you meant JDialog, right?

Comment: "Function to show it"...like setVisible?

Comment: yes, it can be either a function that you implemented which calling it, or either it's constructor which makes all the GUI building and calling it at the end